# How to render a component without its wrapping tag

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

```
<div class='w-full flex relative'>
        <!-- search component -->
        <app-search></app-search>
        <div class='absolute right-0 flex justify-end gap-6'>
            <!-- manipulate nav component-->
            <app-manipulate-nav></app-manipulate-nav>
        </div>
   </div>
```

This is not working as expected
my page should be this [image]
but it render like this [image]
because of component wrapping tag

I have tried to remove component tag on inside devtools(ctrl+shift+I) that was working and i have tried ng-container but that does not work. Any other way to render this??

Comment: First, I assume you are referring to the `app-manipulate-nav` element? This isn't completely clear since there are two component tags in your HTML example. Removing the tag is not necessary to solve your problem. Getting the CSS correct for your component is what you should focus on. Can you include the HTML and CSS for your component?

Comment: No, Actually I'm referring to both component.

Comment: can you help me with rendering component without that wrapping tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try and apply your CSS directly on your `app-manipulate-nav` component.

```
<div class='w-full flex relative'>
        <!-- search component -->
        <app-search></app-search>

        <app-manipulate-nav class='absolute right-0 flex justify-end gap-6'></app-manipulate-nav>
   </div>
```

If it doesn't do the trick, you'll need to share you child component's HTML and CSS. This is a CSS issue, there's no need to "remove the tag" (which is impossible by the way). See the tag as a completely unstyled HTML element.